# Get the content of an input textbox when it's edited

Tags: javascript

I have three input tag, with values pre-coded in:

```
    <input type="text" id="qty1" value="1" style="width:20px"></input>
    <input type="text" id="qty2" value="2" style="width:20px"></input>
    <input type="text" id="qty3" value="2" style="width:20px"></input>
```

Later I have a button (updateQuantities) that, when clicked, should add the values together and post the total somewhere else (quantity_items). However, when I change the contents of the textbox, the "value" attribute doesn't update. Is there any easy quick way to get the current update content of the box?
Here's the javascript that I've made:

```
        <script>
    var num1 = document.getElementById("qty1");
    var num2 = document.getElementById("qty2");
    var num3 = document.getElementById("qty3");
    document.getElementById("updateQuantities").addEventListener("click", function(){update(num1, num2, num3);});
    function update(val1, val2, val3){
        alert(val1);
        var total = val1 + val2 + val3;
        document.getElementById("quantity_items").innerHTML = total;
    }
        </script>
```

Answer (score 3):

Add a .value to the end of your `getElementById`'s.

```
var num1 = document.getElementById("qty1").value;
var num2 = document.getElementById("qty2").value;
var num3 = document.getElementById("qty3").value;
```

Comment: I tried that, but it doesn't get updated. I tried alerting val1 in the function after changing it in the webpage to 5 and it still said 1.

Comment: @TimGraupner Open your browser console and check for errors. If you see any, return here and share the error. This will help offer you a solid solution. You might also want to use something like `parseInt()` on those values before or while adding them together.

Comment: @NewToJS I looked at the errors, and there are some but none of them are related to this. I didn't write the HTML for this page, it's just an assignment for a class where I have to add the single bit of functionality to add these quantities. I changed the adding to Number(val1), and now it works, but only for the original values.

Comment: @TimGraupner rather than adding `.value` while declaring the variables `num1/2/3` add it to your total variable `var total = val1.value + val2.value + val3.value;`